# Is there a flash based web client with both group instant message and voice capabilities that I can modify?

Tags: client, message, voip, voice, instant

I am looking for a flash based web client with both group instant message and voice capabilities that I can modify.  Does anyone know of any open source or proprietary solutions?

Answer (score 0):

[Google Voice](http://www.google.com/googlevoice/about.html)

Answer (score 0):

[TringMe](http://tringme.com/im_gtalk_faq.html) and [Flashphone](http://www.flaphone.com/) are 2 cool re-distributable flash voip/im components

you can mod TringMe with their [developer platform](http://tringme.com/developers.html)